# Is there a shortcut to jump to a certain character on a certain line in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, menu, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm working with imported files in an Eclipse project right now (and they're generated by a program that didn't like using the Enter key, apparently), and when I get an error that says, "Exception on Line 1, Character 25782", it would be incredibly useful to have a way to instantly jump to that character on that line. Are there any menu options or keyboard shortcuts for this? I'm working in Windows, if that helps.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not format the code (Ctrl+Shift+F) to have the single line split into statements?

Comment: I tried both that and Ctrl+Shift+I and neither of those did anything. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: if it's a very long string, I think eclipse won't split it using ctrl+shift+f

Comment: What language is this?